# I can't understand the while loop condition in bubble sort

Tags: java, while-loop, bubble-sort

First, I do understand what the `for` loop does and what the `if` block does

The part that I don't understand is `!isSorted`, if originally isSorted set to `false`, does `!isSorted` mean that it will set the while loop to `true`?

If yes, how come the loop go once again after there was a swap and isSorted flagged to `false`?

Apologies if I could not express myself clearly

It's working, but why it's working ?

```
public class BubbleSorting {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] massiv =  {2,14,8,90,97,44,23,78, 11,1,46, 55, 105,64};
        int buffer;
        boolean isSorted = false;

        while(!isSorted){
            isSorted = true;
            for(int i = 0; i<massiv.length-1; i++){
                if(massiv[i]>massiv[i+1]){
                    buffer = massiv[i];
                    massiv[i] = massiv[i+1];
                    massiv[i+1] = buffer;
                    isSorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv));
    }
}
```

Comment: And no, `!` by itself doesn't set any variables.  It returns a result, which `while` tests, but it doesn't assign `=` the value to any variable.

Comment: The way to read !isSorted is "not is sorted" . If no swaps have occured inside for loop, that means that the array is sorted and is sorted is true.

Comment: @GBlodgett !isSorted is a unary operator applied to a boolean variable. isSorted == false is a test for equality. They are not equivalent.

Comment: @nicomp I'm not sure how they differ in this context though.  Both return the same result.

Comment: @GBlodgett and markspace thanks for your input. I was thinking that if isSorted = false, than (! isSorted) would be same as saying isSorted = true. I thought that ! is inverting the boolean value. Or I didn't catch the idea ?

Comment: Think of it like this. The loop will only run if it evaluates to `while(true)`. `!` will not change the actual variable `isSorted`, but will return the negated/inverted value. So if `isSorted` is true, it will return false and the loop condition will be `while(false)` and the loop will exit. If it is false it will be `while(true)`, and the loop will run again

Comment: @nicomp It appears I am still the student

Comment: @GBlodgett We are all students and you are one of the good ones!

Comment: @nicomp *expressions though, not only variables ;)

Comment: @nicomp Yes but some of us are good teachers as well as good students ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tigran, in response your latest comment, I'll try to explain in a simple way that is easy to understand.

A *conditional* (or conditional statement), in Java or most other programming languages, is a statement that performs different actions depending on whether a certain *condition* is true or false.

In this case, the *condition* is the value of isSorted. The variable isSorted is a boolean variable, so it can have a value of either *true* or *false*.

When we get to a line that says:

```
while(isSorted)
```

we are checking the condition in parentheses, which is isSorted. This means we are checking if isSorted is true. If it is, then we perform the action (enter the loop). If not, we do not.

The "!" symbol means negation - and when used before a condition inside a conditional statement, it means "the opposite of the condition".

So in the line:

```
while(!isSorted)
```

we are checking if the opposite of the isSorted condition is true, meaning isSorted is false. If it is, then we perform the action (enter the loop). If not, we do not.

So in this case, we will only enter the while loop if the value of isSorted is false. If the value becomes true, we will stop entering the loop.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185638/discussion-on-answer-by-yuvalg-i-cant-understand-the-while-loop-condition-in-bu).

Answer (score 0):

First `isSorted` is set to `false` So `!isSorted` means the negation of `isSorted` variable's value and its `true`. So it will go inside while loop.

Then inside first it set to `true`. And if a swap happens it will set to `false`. So until swaps happens `isSorted` is false. That means `!isSorted` is true. So until swaps happens while loop will go on.

And when a swap is not happening. `isSorted` will be true and `!isSorted` will be false. Then it exists the while loop

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operation does not change the **value** of the variable but it inverts the resulting expression that it is used in.

```
boolean first = true;
if (first) {} //`first` is equal to "true" and the expression is "true";

boolean second = !first;
if (second) {}  //`first` is still equal to "true".
                //`second` is equal to "false".
                //the expression is "false".


if (!second) {}     //`first` is still equal to "true".
                    //`second` is still equal to "false".
                    //the expression is "true".
```

---

This is a form of optimization in the bubble sort algorithm. Each time the code does a pass, it assumes the list is now sorted until a swap happens in the pass, meaning the array/list is not sorted yet.

Let's break the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] massiv =  {2,14,8,90,97,44,23,78, 11,1,46, 55, 105,64}; 
    int buffer;
    boolean isSorted = false; // massiv is not sorted,

    while(!isSorted){   // ! isSorted == (is not sorted [yup captain obvious])

        /*here's the tricky part*/
        isSorted = true; // assume the array is sorted already


        for(int i = 0; i < massiv.length-1; i++) { // for each element of the array... 
            if(massiv[i]>massiv[i+1]) { /* ... check if the current value 
                                            is greater than the next */
                // if it's the case, swap those values
                buffer = massiv[i];
                massiv[i] = massiv[i+1];
                massiv[i+1] = buffer;
                isSorted = false; /* the array was not sorted because there
                                     was at least one swap */
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv));
```

So basically, each pass is a validation the array is sorted and if the pass hits an unsorted section, it makes the swap and make the code check one more time until the array is sorted.